# Javascript syntax error when finding multiples of 3 and 5 under 1000

Tags: javascript

```
function multiple(){
  var arr=[]
  for (var i =0; i<1000;i++){
    (i%3==0 || i%5==0) : arr.push(i) ? continue
  }
  return arr.reduce(function(sum,i){sum+=i;return sum})
}
console.log(multiple())
```

error:

```
(i%3==0 || i%5==0) : arr.push(i) ? continue
                     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Comment: title of this post should be "3 OR 5" not "3 AND 5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is because you need to reverse the : and ? to write a proper ternary operator

```
(i%3==0 || i%5==0) ? arr.push(i) : continue
```

Although to be honest you don't really need the ternary operator anyway since that would be the only line of your loop. The continue would effectively skip nothing and actually as pointed out can't be used as an expression.

Just use a basic conditional

```
if(i%3==0 || i%5==0) {
  arr.push(i);
}
```

Comment: This will not fix the problem, as `continue` is a statement, not an expression.

Comment: Another more javascript way of doing it is `(i % 3 || i % 5) && arr.push(i);`

Comment: Why is that 'more javascript', other than the fact that javascript would allow that to work properly? Seems like unnecessary complexity

Comment: @Rich I totally agree, the following is enough and universally known : `if (i % 3 || i % 5) arr.push(i);`.

Comment: Actually re-reading it, both of those will not work because, for example, if the number is divisible by 3 then i % 3 will result in the number 0 which evaluates to falsy not truthy. So that would instead return any number that is NOT divisible by 3 AND 5. Thus going full circle back to the unnecessary complexity part.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. I have a question @Pointy, why continue as a statement not an expression make it not working properly?

Comment: To clarify what he said, the keyword 'continue' is only a javascript statement (code that is itself a line of code) and not a javascript expression (code that can evaluate as part of a statement). http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_statements.asp

Comment: @user3366240 it's just the syntax of the language. The `? :` operator is part of the expression grammar, and all parts of it have to be expressions. The `continue` statement is not an expression.

Comment: If the answer works for you, then you can select it as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just returning the sum you can simply do

```
function multiple() {
    var sum = 0;
    for( var i=0 ; i<1000 ; ++i ) if( i%3==0 || i%5==0 ) sum += i;
    return sum;
}
```